# Proof of using a literal from known set, inside a computed formula

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, private-set-intersection

Suppose I have publicly revealed the value of  $\phi(u) = A+Bu$,
where A, B, u are *private* values from a large group, that I want to keep in secret.

Furthermore, I want to add proof that the value $u$ is from a publicly known set of values, without revealing its real value.

1. How can I do that?
2. Same question with proof about $A$

I thought about:

- A zero-knowledge scheme, but it seems to be inadequate to that purpose because the value $u$ is publicly known.
- Private set intersection - But since $u$ is from a publicly known set I might reveal its value.

Comment: You said there's a group, but you've used addition _and_ multiplication, so there's obviously more than just a group here.  Is there actually a ring structure?  A field?

Comment: If you have a field, then for any value $p = \phi(u)$ and any $u′$, one can presumably pick $A' = 0$ and let $B' = p\cdot (u')^{-1}$, and then you get $p = A' + B' u'$, so no matter what $A$, $B$, and $u$ were to begin with, given $p$ you can fabricate an $A'$, $B'$, and $u'$ also matching the structure $p = \phi'(u') = A' + B' u'$.

Comment: Probably this does not work, unless you specify more of the formula. All those private values don't even exist from the point of view of the verifier - and there is nothing to check. You basically publish a random element, and we can only guess there might be values $A,B$ for every $u,\phi$. Which means the construction has no relvance.

Answer (score 1):

In Crypto 94, Cramer, Damgård and Schoenmakers proposed *Proofs of Partial Knowledge and Simplified Design of Witness Hiding Protocols* with abstract below:

Suppose we are given a proof of knowledge $P$ in which a prover demonstrates that he knows a solution to a given problem instance. Suppose also that we have a secret sharing scheme $S$ on $n$ participants. Then under certain assumptions on $P$ and $S,$ we show how to transform $P$ into a witness indistinguishable protocol, in which the prover demonstrates knowledge of the solution to some subset of $n$ problem instances out of a collection of subsets defined by $S.$

For example, using a threshold scheme, the prover can show that he knows at least $d$ out of $n$ solutions without revealing which $d$ instances are involved. If the instances are independently generated, we get a witness hiding protocol, even if $P$ did not have this property.

Our results can be used to efficiently implement general forms of group oriented identification and signatures. Our transformation produces a protocol with the same number of rounds as $P$ and communication complexity $n$ times that of $P.$ Our results use no unproven complexity assumptions.

The authors also state:

> Our techniques are to some extent related to those of De Santis et al. The models are quite different, however: They consider non-interactive proofs of membership, while we consider interactive proofs of knowledge.

The paper is available [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eberry/papers/crypto94.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

1- Maybe you could use the [CDS protocol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_Cramer-Damgard-Schoenmakers) (sorry, link content is in Spanish, I could not find any Wikipedia English page but the maths are valid though). While $u$ is from a public set, it should still remain secret. The CDS is usually used for voting system, where $u$ belongs to the set $\{0,1\}$ (yes or no). It is indeed a "Zk-proof" approach but it is quite "*light*" as long as $u$ does not belong to a "big" set.

Comment: Cramer-Damgard-Schoenmakers did introduce an OR proof, that works exactly by proving the "true" statement and simulating all others, connected together with a sum of challenges of each sub-protocol instance.